# Powershell foreach-object with embedded switch not working out

Tags: powershell, foreach, switch-statement

Trying to total up the purchased time from text email. Here is the code that I have and I'm hoping it's close enough to explain what I'm trying to do. Makes sense to me but not posh.

```
$n = select-string -Path "$global:EMLpath\*.eml" -Pattern "[ORDER #" -SimpleMatch -CaseSensitive -Context 0,10
$n.Context.PostContext|
          ForEach-Object{
            Switch -Wildcard ($Inputstring = $_) {
                $Inputstring -like "Hourly*" {$ADDhrs = 1 * (-split "$Inputstring")[4]}
                $Inputstring -like "Weekly*" {$ADDhrs = 168 * (-split "$Inputstring")[4]}
                $Inputstring -like "Monthly*" {$ADDhrs = 720 * (-split "$Inputstring")[4]}
                $Inputstring -like "Yearly*" {$ADDhrs = 8640 * (-split "$Inputstring")[4]}
             }
 }
```

The pertinent text in the file is:

```
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
New Order: #1667
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

You’ve received the following order from Joe Shmo:

[ORDER #1667] (2022-04-28)

Monthly Server Rental X 1 = $26.56
Weekly Server Rental X 2 = $26.56


==========
```

Comment: You need to wrap the expressions inside `{ ... }` so they're evaluated. i.e.: `{ $Inputstring -like "Hourly*" } { .... }` but since you're already using `-Wildcard` there is no need for the expression at all. Each input object is evaluated against a wildcard pattern, so simply, `"Hourly*" { result here }` is enough.

Comment: What would be your expected result from this ? and, how many Orders can be in the pertinent text ?

Comment: Generally speaking, there's probably only going to be 1 item purchased but had to allow for oddballs out there. ;) 
My math was not working out so made additional changes to code and with Santiago's help the code now works correct. I will add an answer with corrected code.

Comment: You should self-answer instead of posting the solution in the question. You can also accept your own answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Santiago, this works now.

```
$n = select-string -Path "$global:EMLpath\*.eml" -Pattern "[ORDER #" -SimpleMatch -CaseSensitive -Context 0,10
$ADDhrs = 0
$n.Context.PostContext|
          ForEach-Object{
            Switch -Wildcard ($Inputstring = $_) {
                "Hourly*" {$ADDhrs = $ADDhrs + (1 * (-split "$Inputstring")[4])}
                "Weekly*" {$ADDhrs = $ADDhrs + (168 * (-split "$Inputstring")[4])}
                "Monthly*" {$ADDhrs = $ADDhrs + (720 * (-split "$Inputstring")[4])}
                "Yearly*" {$ADDhrs = $ADDhrs + (8640 * (-split "$Inputstring")[4])}
             }
 }
```